# How to pass a list of strings as individual arguments to subprocess?

Tags: python, list, subprocess, popen

I would like to merge PDFs using pdfbox using a subprocess in Python.

This is what I got, but it's not working as expected.

```
import subprocess
from subprocess import Popen

def merger(pdfList):
    try:
        output = "output.pdf"
        result = Popen(["java", "-jar", "pdfbox-app-2.0.19.jar", "PDFMerger", "\
        {}".format(pdfList), "{}".format(output)], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, \
        stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
        result_subprocess = result.communicate()
        if result.returncode != 0 or len(result_subprocess[1])>0:
            raise Exception(result_subprocess[1].decode())
        else:
            return True
    except Exception as e:
        print("Exception:",str(e))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    pdfList = ["33.pdf","4.pdf"]
    merger(pageList)
```

This is the exception that I ran into.

```
('Exception:', 'Usage: java -jar pdfbox-app-x.y.z.jar PDFMerger <inputfiles 2..n> <outputfile>\n\nOptions:\n <inputfiles 2..n> : 2 or more source PDF documents to merge\n <outputfile>
```

Comment: "it's not working" is not telling what happened. What did happen? Did you get extra PDFs? Did the PDFs become self-aware and feel uncomfortable? Did you computer screen freeze? Did the CPU go 100%? Did you get a message "do not press the red button again"?

Comment: What did you expect exactly? What happened instead?

Comment: @TilmanHausherr, This is the exception that am running into ('Exception:', 'Usage: java -jar pdfbox-app-x.y.z.jar PDFMerger <inputfiles 2..n> <outputfile>\n\nOptions:\n  <inputfiles 2..n> : 2 or more source PDF documents to merge\n  <outputfile>      : The PDF document to save the merged documents to\n\n')

Comment: @Grismar I want the two pdfs to be merged into a single one. But am running into exception.

Comment: You're passing `"{}".format(pdfList)` in as an argument to `PDFMerger`, which is `"['33.pdf', '4.pdf']"` - what you're seeing is not a Python exception, it's PDFMerger's output telling you you're not calling it correctly. Also, instead of adding information in comments, please just edit your question.

Comment: I don't know python, does format put a space between the input files?

Comment: Further thought on this: apparently each string element in the array passed to Popen is one command line component. Does it work if several files are in one component, which you did? `"{}".format(pdfList)`

Comment: @TilmanHausherr, what i did is according to the document. https://pdfbox.apache.org/1.8/commandline.html#decrypt

Comment: You're passing an array to Popen, right? I suspect that "{}".format(pdfList) will not produce two array elements, but only one array element named "33.pdf4.pdf" or   "33.pdf 4.pdf". Try passing each file name sepsrately to test my theory, i.e. `Popen(["java", "-jar", "pdfbox-app-2.0.19.jar", "PDFMerger",  "33.pdf", "4.pdf", "output.pdf"] etc` to see if that works or what happens.